# Java Regex Help: Splitting String on spaces, "=>", and commas

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a string on any of the following sequences:

1 or more spaces
0 or more spaces, followed by a comma, followed by 0 or more spaces,
0 or more spaces, followed by "=>", followed by 0 or more spaces

Haven't had experience doing Java regexs before, so I'm a little confused. Thanks!

Example:
add  r10,r12 => r10
store r10 => r1

Comment: You should give a real example.

Comment: no the target data is just any sort of string.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just create regex matching any of your three cases and pass it into `split` method:

```
string.split("\\s*(=>|,|\\s)\\s*");
```

Regex here means literally

1. Zero or more whitespaces (`\\s*`)
2. Arrow, or comma, or whitespace (`=>|,|\\s`)
3. Zero or more whitespaces (`\\s*`)

You can replace whitespace `\\s` (detects spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc) with plain space character  if necessary.

Comment: The brackets are not necessary. And of course `\s` matches more than just spaces which may or may not be what the OP wanted...

Comment: It might be not enough: for "word1 ,=>word2" it return 3 items but not 2

Comment: @ses According to the problem description, your input should result in three strings: "word1", "", "word2".

Answer (score 16):

#### Strictly translated

For simplicity, I'm going to interpret you indication of "space" () as "any whitespace" (`\s`).

Translating your spec more or less "word for word" is to delimit on any of:

- 1 or more spaces

  - `\s+`
- 0 or more spaces (`\s*`), followed by a comma (`,`), followed by 0 or more spaces (`\s*`)

  - `\s*,\s*`
- 0 or more spaces (`\s*`), followed by a "=>" (`=>`), followed by 0 or more spaces (`\s*`)

  - `\s*=>\s*`

To match any of the above: `(\s+|\s*,\s*|\s*=>\s*)`

#### Reduced form

However, your spec can be "reduced" to:

- 0 or more spaces

  - `\s*`,
- followed by either a space, comma, or "=>"

  - `(\s|,|=>)`
- followed by 0 or more spaces

  - `\s*`

Put it all together: `\s*(\s|,|=>)\s*`

The reduced form gets around some corner cases with the strictly translated form that makes some unexpected empty "matches".

#### Code

Here's some code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Temp {

    // Strictly translated form:
    //private static final String REGEX = "(\\s+|\\s*,\\s*|\\s*=>\\s*)";

    // "Reduced" form:
    private static final String REGEX = "\\s*(\\s|=>|,)\\s*";

    private static final String INPUT =
        "one two,three=>four , five   six   => seven,=>";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        final String[] items = p.split(INPUT);
        // Shorthand for above:
        // final String[] items = INPUT.split(REGEX);
        for(final String s : items) {
            System.out.println("Match: '"+s+"'");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Match: 'one'
Match: 'two'
Match: 'three'
Match: 'four'
Match: 'five'
Match: 'six'
Match: 'seven'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split(" *(,|=>| ) *");
```

should do it.