# How can I split a String by all whitespace or commas

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string

```
Dim nSet As String() = "1   3, 5,6".Split(",| ")
```

The array would then be:

```
1   3
5
6
```

---

I looked at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654446/java-regex-help-splitting-string-on-spaces-and-commas) and tried to implement that regex:

```
Dim nSet As String() = "1   3, 5,6".Split("\\s*(,|\\s)\\s*")
```

But the array was just:

```
1   3, 5,6
```

---

#### Expected Output

I just need an array where each element has a single number, **or** a single number and any amount of whitespace (because then I can use `.Trim` on the element).

I want to be able to get the array to be:

```
1
3
5
6
```

I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic Studio 2010 Express. I'm not sure what language it specifically uses, but it's different than the C languages in ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Dim separators() As String = {",", " "}
Dim nSet As String() = "1   3, 5,6".Split(separators, 
                                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: This works. Is there any reason why I need `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` ? *I* don't mind empty entries because I just ignore them in my For loop. Just wondering.

Comment: @mikeyaworski, just a good rule of thumb to not worry about some input format errors

Comment: This way you don't have to worry about them in your `For` loop either

Comment: @KonradKokosa: it's not a good rule of thumb to modify the content by default. It depends on the actual requirement if you for example want to remove empty lines (if you split by `Environment.NewLine`). If you split columns in a csv-file you even get an incorrect number of columns if some of them are empty. So `StringSplitOptions.None` should be default.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim nSet As String() = "1   3, 5,6".Split({" ", ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

You could use `ParamArray separators() As Char` overload, but it would return a lot of empty items:

```
Dim nSet As String() = "1   3, 5,6".Split(" "c, ","c)
```

Comment: Thanks for the note about the overload. Both of these work for me.